# What set number is this?

Tags: set-identification

I have a set here that is mixed in with a bunch of other Lego, and no instruction book. I know 100% these pieces belong with it. Is there anyone who can identify the set for me so I can find instructions for it? It has a staircase piece and a 6179 piece that says “Gold Mine” with a base plate number 2359 in a sand colour. [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parts shown in your picture are from [Bandit's Secret Hide-Out (6161)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=6761-1) set. [Here](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=6761-1) you can find inventory of this set to collect all the parts. [Baseplate, Road 32 x 32 7-Stud Curve with Rocks and Ruts Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2359px2#T=C) is unique to this set.

[image]

Comment: Yes! That’s it. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi @KatieS86, welcome to Bricks! If Alex has answered your question, you can click the "tick" under the vote buttons to mark it as "the answer", which helps us all know that your question is answered and both you and Alex get some reputation ;)